# Mapping through an array of objects returns unnecessary comma character in markup

Tags: javascript, arrays

[Screenshot of comma in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtSzY.jpg)

Hello, I am building gold shop website and i have an array of objects.
I am mapping through an array of objects to get products displayed on the main page. However, there is an extra comma character in the output displayed which I don't need. Can anyone help me fix this? You can see the images

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'ძველი ქარხნული საათი',
    prob: 583,
    weight: 19.74,
    price: 2100,
    img1: 'img/watchWm1.jpg',
    img2: 'img/watchWm.jpg',
    category: 'watch',
    gender: 'woman'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'ძველი ქარხნული საათის ბრასლეტი',
    prob: 583,
    weight: 13.5,
    price: 2000,
    img1: 'img/watchBracletWm.jpg',
    img2: '',
    category: 'bracelet',
    gender: 'woman'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'ძველი ქარხნული საათის ბრასლეტი',
    prob: 583,
    weight: 22.15,
    price: 3300,
    img1: 'img/watchBracletWm2.jpg',
    img2: '',
    category: 'bracelet',
    gender: 'woman'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'გრაციელას ბრენდის ბრასლეტი',
    prob: 750,
    weight: 27.3,
    price: 5400,
    img1: 'img/4.jpg',
    img2: '',
    category: 'bracelet',
    gender: 'woman'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'იტალიური ქარხნული ბრასლეტი(კაცის)',
    prob: 585,
    weight: 42.91,
    price: 6000,
    img1: 'img/5.jpg',
    img2: '',
    category: 'bracelet',
    gender: 'man'
  }
];

//Display All Products on Main Page
var productsOuterDiv = document.getElementById('productsOuterDiv');
const productsBox = products.map(product => `<div class='productDiv'>
      <div class='imgDiv'>
      <img src='${product.img1}' alt='${product.title}'>
      </div>
      <h6><strong>${product.title}</strong></h6>
      <p><strong>წონა:</strong> ${product.weight} გრამი</p>
      <p><strong>სინჯი(პრობი):</strong> ${product.prob}</p>
      <p><strong>ფასი:</strong> ${product.price} ლარი</p>
      <button class='btn btn-details'>დეტალურად</button>
    </div>`);
productsOuterDiv.innerHTML = productsBox;
```

Comment: there is the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array, when you `productsOuterDiv.innerHTML = productsBox;` it runs toString which separates them with a comma. Use join

```
productsOuterDiv.innerHTML = productsBox.join('');
```

```js
var arr = [`<span>1</span>`,`<span>2</span>`,`<span>3</span>`];

document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = arr;
document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = arr.join("");
```

```css
span{ border: 1px dashed #CCC; }
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="out2"></div>
```

Comment: See in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#description) where it describes how arrays are automatically converted to strings by converting all the elements to strings, then joining them together with commas.